# Using Tablesorter in dynamically created tabs filled by ajax

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, jquery-ui-tabs

I encountered a problem that on first sight seems to be largely discussed, but all the hints I found did not help. So I try an own thread now.

I'm using jQuery to create a database frontend, that searches for annual reports and shows them in a table, one table for one year. Each table is placed into a jQuery tab. These tabs are dynamically created. So I can have tabs for 2001, 2003 and so on. The content of each tab is dynamically loaded via the ajax functionality of the tabs.

This is the script creating the tabs. In the html body is a starter tab created, that will be deleted in the following:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
           $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ cache:true });

        saYears = $.grep(saYears, function(v, k){
                  return $.inArray(v ,saYears) === k;
                 });

       for(var i=0; i < saYears.length; 
       {
         $("div#tabs ul").append(
              "<li><a href='dbfunctions/GetEntriesForYear.php?year="+saYears[i]"'>" + 
                   saYears[i] + "</a></li>"
              );

        if(i === 0)
         {
           // Deletes the "starter tab"
           $('#tabs ul:first li:eq(0) a').remove();
         }

         $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
       }
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", saYears.length-1 );
   });

    </script>
```

Here is a scratch, on how the table is created from the GetEntriesForYear.php file the tab is pointing to. The leading div error$year is for testing purposes:

```
echo "<div id='error$year'></div>";
echo "<div id='hitlist-$year' class='ui-widget'>";
echo "<table id='table$year' class='tablesorter' class='ui-widget'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr align='left'>";
echo "<th>Document date</th>";
echo "<th>Author</th>";
echo "<th>Keywords</th>";
echo "<tbody overflow:scroll>";
  GetEntriesNow($year);
echo "</tbody></table></div>";
```

The function filling the table is doing what its expected to do:

```
print "<td>" . $entry['date'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $entry['document_reporter'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $entry['keyword_' + $i] . "</td>";
```

Plus some db stuff. This all works well and as expected.

My problem now is, when and how to call `$('#table2013').tablesorter()`. I tried some hints for events like ajaxStop, create/load/activate on the tabs but no sorting will be done. Does anybody has a hint where what to use and where to place?

Comment: Put the script at the beginning of `GetEntriesForYear.php`.

Comment: Hello? Are you still out there?

Comment: Sorry. Had to look after my children. Back again now.

Answer (score 0):

**`GetEntriesForYear.php`**:

```
<?php
$year = $_GET['year'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../tablesorter/themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" id="" media="print, projection, screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jQuery/ui/css/start/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">
<script src="../jQuery/ui/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../jQuery/ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#table<?=$year;?>').tablesorter();
    $('#error<?=$year;?>').html('accessed tab for year $year');
});
</script>
<?
function GetEntriesNow($year)
{
    session_start();
    $startDate = $year ."-01-01";
    $endDate =  $year ."-12-31";
    $results = PgsqlDB::GetEntries($startDate, $endDate);
    foreach ($results as $entry) {
        print "<td>" . $entry['date'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $entry['document_reporter'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $entry['keyword_' + $i] . "</td>";
    }
}
echo "<div id='error$year'></div>";
echo "<div id='hitlist-$year' class='ui-widget'>";
echo "<table id='table$year' class='tablesorter' class='ui-widget'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr align='left'>";
echo "<th>Document date</th>";
echo "<th>Author</th>";
echo "<th>Keyword</th>";
echo "<tbody overflow:scroll>";
GetEntriesNow($year);
echo "</tbody></table></div>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I tried to implement your suggestion, but the result is exactly the same. The table is shown properly but not sortable. Here is, what I have done:

Comment: I have re-written the code EXACTLY as it should be entered, please try it now.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it in the evening and tell you the results.

Comment: I did not get it to work. Initially it did not show any table output so I added 'php' to the opener '<?' and I got the tables but unsorted. There were no text in the error-div. So might it possibly not be accessed?